# Calculating inner product of an array

Tags: javascript

```
// Write a program to calculate the innerproduct of two arrays (ip of v,w = sum, for all i, of vi*wi)

var v = [1, 2, 3, 'x'];
var w = [1, 2, 3, 4];
vSum_total = 0;
wSum_total = 0;

// calculate sum of v
for(i=0; i<v.length; i++)
{
    if (isNaN(v[i]))
    v[i] = 0
    else
    vSum_total += Number(v[i]);
}

// calculate sum of w
for(i=0; i<v.length; i++)
{
    if (isNaN(v[i]))
    v[i] = 0
    else
    wSum_total += Number(w[i]);
}

alert ("Total of v: " + (vSum_total));
alert ("Total of w: " + (wSum_total));
alert ("Inner product: " + (vSum_total * wSum_total));
```

I'm trying to calculate the inner product of an array but my result isn't alerting. Any hints in the right direction would be really appreciated!

Comment: Stupid question: is `vSum_total` initialized to the value `1`?

Comment: BTW, calculating an 'inner product' requires two vectors, not one

Comment: what is `vSum`? did you mean just `v`

Comment: "My result isn't alerting" ???

Comment: Sorry about the confusion guys... I've updated the code!

Comment: Ok, so now that you've completely changed the code, does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since vsum starts as 0, when you multiply it by any number it stays 0.

Comment: `vsum` does indeed start at 0. But OP is using `vSum_total`.

Comment: This is assuming that vsum_total is vsum and that you are adding v[i] to the total and not vsum[i].

Answer (score 2):

```
var vSum = 1;

var v = [];
v[0] = parseInt(prompt("v0:"));
v[1] = parseInt(prompt("v1:"));
v[2] = parseInt(prompt("v2:"));
v[3] = parseInt(prompt("v3:"));

// calculate ip of v
for(i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
{
    vSum *= v[i];
}

alert(vSum);
```

Comment: Explanations are better than code dumps. Code snippets are a great way to embellish a post, but explaining what the OP did wrong is the best way to provide an answer.

Comment: Yeah I should have added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`vSum` should be `v` (or vice versa).

You are trying to use an integer like an array, so your script is aborting.

Turn on your debugger.

Comment: Not to mention what is vSum_total ? Is that even defined anywhere.